# Devise current_user with single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-table-inheritance

I have a user model with an admin submodel.

```
class Admin < User
end
```

I have devise set up and a 'type' column in the user model. The routes look like this:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'sessions' }, :skip => :registrations
devise_for :admins, :skip => :sessions
```

I am unclear on how to override devise so I can access an admin using the current_user helper.

Right now name is undefined from `<%= current_user.name %>`

Is an admin not also a user? I'm not sure why current_user is nil.

In my sessions_controller I have:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    rtn = super
    sign_in(resource.type.underscore, resource.type.constantize.send(:find, resource.id)) unless resource.type.nil?
    rtn
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting your app after you made your last changes?

Comment: Ah that make current_admin available. Any clue on how to make current_user work?

Comment: The `name` attribute is on User or on Admin?

Comment: Name is a user attribute